# How to get URL response through Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to fetch response through URL using javascript but readystate ab=nd status is not getting 4 and 200 respectively. When the Url is fetched directly its working but not through the code.

```
!<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <head>
    <script>    
      var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      document.write("1");
      var url='http://10.64.10.222:5000/';
      document.write("2");
      Http.open("GET",url);
      document.write("3");
      Http.send();
      document.write("4");
      document.write(Http.readyState);
      document.write(Http.status);
      Http.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(Http.readyState == 4 && Http.status == 200 ){
          document.write("6");
          document.write(Http.responseText);
        }
        document.write("5");
      }  
    </script>
  </head>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error message? Also please give [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no error message it is not going into "if" loop and sorry for the bad example. I just want to know why readyState and status is not getting 4 and 200 respectively.

Comment: Try putting `Http.onreadystatechange` before `Http.open` or `Http.send`. It could be because that state has already changed before you capture the value

Comment: Still getting value of readystate and status as 0

Comment: Sorry, it would very difficult to know what is wrong without verifiable example. I would suggest you to try to change your method of fetching

Comment: ok thank you Andreas :)

Answer (score 0):

why using tradional and old XMLHttpRequest, use latest [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). taken from the MDN

> The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including
>   across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used
>   XMLHttpRequest, but it provides a more powerful and flexible feature set.

demo snippet is as below, there are many options to read headers and status code as wll.

```
fetch('http://10.64.10.222:5000/')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```